# How to get correct screen width and height in iOS 16 when rotate screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios16

I got wrong width and height when rotate screen. It works in iOS 15;

[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.width will return the height.

[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.height will return the width.

They exchanged values

I try to use "setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations" but failed.

Is there any solution to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using viewWillTransition function instead:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    // Your other code ... 
    // reAssign values to height and width variable here when rotated
}
```

Comment: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.width
This is used for the entire app, and it is impossible to modify every page.

Comment: you need to check for device orientation then